# Angular UI Grid vertical scroll issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-grid

I am adding height as 281px to .ui-grid-viewport. Also had to add row height as 55px. I need to show the rows in 300px height box. I face vertical scroll flicker issue when the row count is > 6 and less than 10. 1t works fine for >=10 rows.

Comment: hello, welcome to stack overflow. and?... you need to show us some code, we can't help you if we don't now what you're doing.

Comment: I need to use word-wrap to show the full content of cell. If we increase the data the mouse scroll works fine. Currently mouse wheel  tries to reach to the top.  Please check the link. https://plnkr.co/edit/qNVztaGP38rdZyXPHQss?p=preview

Comment: I'm testing this on Safari on a Mac computer. in your main.css get rid of overflow in .ui-grid-cell>div and in .ui-grid-row. the flicker goes away, but grid still tries to go top after scroll, there is some javascript I'm not seeing

Comment: Thank you :). The flickering is not there now but for grid trying to to go top after scroll i have not added any javascript.

Comment: I am facing same problem, and in attached plunker, It is still flickering, if you scroll down. Any solution?